# No selected items in the ListBoxFor should show validation error in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, selection, html.listboxfor

I show the Delete View in a partial/dialog. Initially no items are selected.
When the user clicks the ok button the Delete Post action and its parameter selectedIds is NULL. Thats ok, but how can I show the user an error message?

When I reach the code "return PartialView" then I get an Exception in the View, that my Model.DisplayList ist empty.

I know I seem to mix 2 problems here but I guess one could solve the other...

Delete Actions:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Delete()
        {
            var templates = _templateDataProvider.GetTemplates();
            var listViewModel = new ListViewModel<Template>();
            listViewModel.DisplayList = templates;
            return PartialView(listViewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int[] selectedIds)
        {
            if (selectedIds == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Nothing selected");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }

            return PartialView();
        }
```

Delete View:

```
@model ITMS.ViewModels.ListViewModel<ITMS.Models.Template>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Template"))
{ 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)      
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedIds, new SelectList(Model.DisplayList, "Id", "Name"),new { @class = "select"} )
}
```

When I return this:

```
return PartialView(new ListViewModel<Template> { DisplayList = _templateDataProvider.GetTemplates() });
```

then it works, but I do not want to access the database again for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Delete POST action when there is an exception and you redisplay the partial view you are not passing any model to this view. And yet your view needs a DisplayList property in order to load the list box. So make sure you are passing a model tha same way you did in your GET action:

```
var templates = _templateDataProvider.GetTemplates();
var listViewModel = new ListViewModel<Template>();
listViewModel.DisplayList = templates;
return PartialView(listViewModel);
```

Another possibility is to directly have the Delete action take the view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(ListViewModel<Template> model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }

    // Make sure you rebind the DisplayList property
    model.DisplayList = _templateDataProvider.GetTemplates();
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Now as far as the validation is concerned you could decorate your `SelectedIds` property on the view model with for example the Required attribute:

```
[Required]
public IEnumerable<Template> SelectedIds { get; set; }
```

---

UPDATE:

A performance concern has been expressed in the comments section about accessing the database to load the list again in the POST action. To avoid this performance hit the values could be cached and reused.

Like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Template> GetTemplates()
{
    var templates = HttpContext.Cache["templates"] as IEnumerable<Template>;
    if (templates == null)
    {
        templates = _templateDataProvider.GetTemplates();
        HttpContext.Cache["templates"] = templates;
    }
    return templates;
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Delete()
{
    var listViewModel = new ListViewModel<Template>();
    listViewModel.DisplayList = GetTemplates();
    return PartialView(listViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(ListViewModel<Template> model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }

    model.DisplayList = GetTemplates();
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Comment: Sorry Darin I forgot some code updated now. My ViewModel has a DisplayList property and my model is returned but the database is accessed again... I dont want that. Is there no other chance , do I have to access the dataprovider again? Maybe some tricky code?

Comment: @Elisa, you have to understand that in HTML when you have a `<select>` element **only** the selected value is sent to the server when you submit the form. Another thing that you have to understand is that HTTP is a stateless protocol. So if you don't retrieve this list from somewhere you simply cannot redisplay the view because this view depends on it. If you are afraid that querying the database might have negative performance hit you could cache the results of the `_templateDataProvider.GetTemplates()` call. I have updated my answer to provide an example of how this could be achieved.

Comment: ok thanks Darin. BUT I have to do this:ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Nothing selected"); If I do not set this when the model.SelectedIds is null no error message is shown. I can not annotate my model with a ZeroSelectionRequired attribute althought that would be nice.

Comment: The best way is to use some data annotation on your view model to avoid cluttering your controller action with validation logic. That's not its responsibility. If you can't then please stop using your domain models in the views and start using view models tat you define specifically for the requirements of the given view. And if you don't want to listen my advice, well, you could continue adding validation logic in your controllers.

Comment: But yes therefore I use a ListViewModel. I just use the Templates to fill the viewmodel. Would you do it differently? Nah the data annotation is good advice ;-)

Comment: I would decorate the SelectedIds property on the view model with a data annotation that will perform the validation.

Comment: Just did that: public class ListViewModel<T>
    {
        [Min(1,ErrorMessage="test succeeded")]
        public int[] SelectedIds { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<T> DisplayList { get; set; }        
    } but did NOT work, the ModelState is still VALID!

Comment: Shit man you rock my socks! The required worked! The 3rd party library did not work!

Comment: The annotation for min doesn't go on the property for the list, it goes on the property that holds the value for what is selected from the list. Mine works perfect. Granted, you needed all of those changes that @DarinDimitrov said you needed. I upvoted him